# Is it possible to redeploy Azure Data Factory using ARM Templates

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have production ready Azure Data Factory. I have created a new Data Factory instance and I would like redeploy all the pipelines, activities etc in the new Azure Data Factory instance.

Is it possible to recreate our production ready data factory to the new Data Factory instance?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Simply upload the current ADF Pipelines to GitHub, restore the configuration to a feature branch from the main branch.